# Agrupar registros con pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Estoy tratando de agrupar los registros de un mismo identificador y que queden en una misma 'celda'

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
ide=[1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,12]
articulo=['lavadora','plancha','secadora','estufa','tv','celular','aspiradora','lavadora','nevera','plancha','computador',
         'nevera','auriculares','secadora','estufa','horno microondas','tableta']
lista=[ide,articulo]
df=pd.DataFrame(lista,['identificación','articulo']).transpose()
df
```

Este df arroja esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Logro hacer lo que quiero con el siguiente código

```
data = df["identificación"].unique()
idet=[]
k=[]
for i in data:
    idet.append(i)
    k.append(' - '.join(df[df['identificación']==i]['articulo'].tolist()))
lista2=[idet,k]
dff=pd.DataFrame(lista2,['Identificación','Artículo']).transpose()
```

dff es esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que es lo que busco, pero quiero saber si se puede optimizar, o si hay algo que ya esté establecido y lo realice de una forma más eficiente, o si la que encontré es adecuada.

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil, por favor acéptala, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo puedes lograr utilizando [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) y [`pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html)

```
df.groupby(['identificación'], as_index=False)['articulo'].apply(' - '.join)
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
ide=[1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,12]
articulo=['lavadora','plancha','secadora','estufa','tv','celular','aspiradora','lavadora','nevera','plancha','computador',
         'nevera','auriculares','secadora','estufa','horno microondas','tableta']
lista=[ide,articulo]
df=pd.DataFrame(lista,['identificación','articulo']).transpose()
df1 = df.groupby(['identificación'], as_index=False)['articulo'].apply(' - '.join)
df1
```

Esto devuelve:

```
    identificación  articulo
0   1               lavadora - plancha
1   2               secadora - estufa
2   3               tv - celular - aspiradora - lavadora
3   4               nevera
4   5               plancha
5   6               computador
6   7               nevera
7   8               auriculares
8   9               secadora
9   10              estufa - horno microondas
10  12              tableta
```